# shoulder bone bends like arm problem

Tags: rigging

[image]

I bought character model and I tried to bring into mixamo then shoulder bends like arm. How can I fix this? [image]

Comment: how shall we help you without seeing any of your settings, your model and without any useful information? pls provide blend file and describe detailed the steps you took so we can reproduce your problem. thx.

Comment: We really do need  bit more detail, here, to answer.  A share on https://blend-exchange.com/ would cover a  lot of bases. This post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'

Comment: I am sorry,I attatched blend file.

Comment: How have you imported the model into Mixamo? Just the mesh or the mesh with the armature? I've imported only the mesh, placed the auto rigger marks, and the deformation looks good.

Comment: Thank you for reply,  I imported with the armature. I wish to know how to let mixamo to recognize shoulder bone as shoulder bone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I renamed bones then it recognized as shoulders